# Compensate for the area moved by transform: translate

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to remove the empty area an element leaves behind after it has been moved via transform: translateY. So basically on that code snipped below I want the yellow element to be right below the blue element without the space in between. Because it's for a template I need to achieve this without changing the code of the above or below element.
The element is moved with the percentage of the size of the element. My initial idea was to add

margin-bottom: -50%;

but the 50% are calculated with the width of the element and not the height. Another idea was to make the position absolute. But that doesn't work either since I don't know how big the content of the elements will be.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this with just css?

```css
div {
  padding: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.above {
  background-color: red;
}

.moved {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
}

.below {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="above">
    
  </div>
  <div class="moved">
    
  </div>
  <div class="below">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Just to be a bit more precise:
The divs represent independent sections of my template. Since these are reusable components I can not edit the other sections (below and above). Therefor I'm looking for a solution in which the moved section just uses as much space as it does after the translation.

Comment: did you come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined the height of each one of these `div`s to be 100px, and translated the blue one for 50% of it = 50px, you can add a `margin-bottom: -50px;` and be all set

Comment: Thx for the answer. But as stated I don't know the height of the element since I don't know the content. It's just for a template.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `translateY(-50%)` as well on your yellow element, this will moved it upwards to remove the space between it and the blue.

```
.below {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. But as stated I can't edit the yellow part since it's another template component.